# Proving a set is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that the set $S = \{x\in \Bbb R: x^2-25x > 0\}$ is unbounded.

I started off by assuming by way of contradiction that is has an upper bound, specifically $\beta$ = sup S. I'm getting stuck on where to go from here.

Comment: $x^2 - 25x = x(x-25)$.  if $x - 25 > \sqrt M > 0$ then $x(x-25) > (x - 25)^2 > M$ so is unbounded.

Comment: @fleablood This comment seems to be answering a different question than the one asked.

Comment: "This comment seems to be answering a different question than the one asked."  To put this sentence in the present tense is a little weird considering the comment is five years old.

Comment: But then again.... I dont see why you don't think a comment showing that the values of a set are unbounded are answering a question other than the OPs question about the values of a set being unbounded.

Comment: @fleablood The question asks to show the values of $x$ such that $f(x)>0$ is unbounded.  Your comment appears to be arguing that $f$ is unbounded, which seems only tangentially related.  It’s an easy mistake, I might have done the same and I didn’t intend to make a big fuss of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assume  it is bounded, and then try and show a contradiction. Just show that there are large enough (in absolute value) real numbers satisfying this equality.

For this, simply note that $x^2-25x = x(x-25)$. Hence, this is greater than zero  whenever both are greater than zero, which happens whenever $x>25$. Thus, for any $x > 25$, it follows that $x(x-25)>0$, so $x \in S$, so $S$ is unbounded.

Since you are proceeding by contradiction, we should probably discuss that way as well. So suppose that $\beta = \sup S$. Note that $26 \in S$ (which you verify on your own), so $\beta \geq 26$. Now, consider $\beta+1$. Note that
\begin{align}
(\beta+1)^2-25(\beta+1) &= \beta^2+2\beta+1-25\beta-25 \\
 &\geq \beta^2 -25\beta + 2(26)+1-25 = \beta^2-25\beta + 28\\
 &> \beta^2-25\beta\\
 &> 0
\end{align}
Hence, $\beta+1 \in S$, contradicting that $\beta = \sup S$. Hence, $S$ is unbounded.

Comment: Wouldn't it also hold for x<0 too though?

Comment: @Jay3 Yes it would. You can show that for $x<0$, $x(x-25)$ increases as $x$ decreases.

Comment: The way that a set is defined to be unbounded was that there is a point x$\in$$S$ such that $|x|$ > M for each number M. Is there a way to work this into the fact x >25 and x<0 are both solutions?

Comment: Of course. It is enough to see that for any $M>25$, both the number $M+1$ and $-M-1$ are part of $S$, and are greater than $M$ is absolute value.

Answer (score 4):

Note that:

$$x^2-25x=x(x-25)$$

Hence $S\supset (25,\infty)$, which is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

If $\beta = \sup S$ then $x^2 - 25 x  \le \beta$

So $x^2 - 25x + (25/2)^2 \le \beta + (25/2)^2$

$0 \le (x - 25/2)^2 \le \beta + (25/2)^2$

$x - 25/2 \le \sqrt{\beta + (25/2)^2}$

$x \le \sqrt{\beta + (25/2)^2} + 25/2$.

So just take $x > \sqrt{\beta + (25/2)^2} + 25/2$ and we will have $x^2 - 25 > \beta$.   A contradiction that is unavoidable.

But this isnt a very good way to do it.